# how to import datas to magento 1.7.0.2 db from magento 1.4.1.1

Tags: magento

I have a magento site version 1.4.1.1.

I upgraded the site to magento 1.7.0.2. in a sub domain, with another db.

That means now i have :

```
domain                 db              version

example.com         magento_cart       1.4.1.1
test.example.com    magento_test       1.7.0.2
```

The client now using the `example.com` site and he added products into that db daily.

before upgrading the magento site in sub domain i did the following steps:

```
1.Take a backup from main domain.
2.import that backup into sub domain's db.
3.take a copy of all files in main domain and put it into sub domain.
(Now in sub domain there have a working copy of main domain in sub domain)

4.then upgraded the magento site to 1.7.0.2 in sub domian.
```

When i doing this upgrading in sub domain ,the client also added some more products and purchased some more products.That means now the new db and old db are different with theris datas.That means in old db there have some more products.So i want to import that datas to the corressponding tables into the new db.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

here's few links on same matter on SO already

[Moving magento site from one server to another server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11739642/moving-magento-site-from-one-server-to-another-server/11742397#11742397)

[Best practice for conducting a Magento update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757775/best-practice-for-conducting-a-magento-update/11767694#11767694)

[configuring compatible development and production sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808235/configuring-compatible-development-and-production-sites/11808793#comment15738750_11808793)

Comment: ,,My site is working prefectly but the last added products is not there.It is in main domain's databse.I want to only insert that datas of products into dub domain's tables

Comment: syncing those databases is really hard to perform and is easier to just repeat the upgrade process

Answer (score 0):

if its just products you want to upgrade, the easiest way (I think) Is to export through csv - system>import/export>profiles.  Do all products, make sure the media folder is copied across so the pics are in place.  you can make sure of the relative pic address in the csv.  then import into the new shop.